# html base element on 'a' element only

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use the HTML 'base' element to change my base directory. But I only want the base directory to be changed for my 'a' elements and not for my script and style includes.

So I found out that I can use base element but I think I cannot really change anything further than this.

```
<base href="https://example.com/">

//Don't change root for this:
<script src="../js/example.js"></script>

//Only change root for this:
<a href="../example">example</a>
```

Does anyone know how I could make this work? Maybe javascript or something. But I cannot find anything about this.

I got something like this: (doesn't work)

```
$('a').each(function() {
     var value = $(this).attr('href');
     $(this).attr('href', 'new/root/' + value);
});
```

Comment: It'll change all relative URLs within your document. IMO there is no option to apply only of 'a' tag. But you can use javascript instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow. The easiest way to do this is to grab all the anchor tags by using `querySelectorAll`. Once you've grabbed all the elements, we can use `forEach` to iterate over each anchor tag with a function.

The function will grab the `href` attribute using `getAttribute`. Once we have the `href` we use `replace` to run a quick regular expression that finds all dots and slashes and replace them with empty characters. Now that we removed these characters we can reassign the href using `setAttribute`.

```
const allAnchorTags = document.querySelectorAll('a');

allAnchorTags.forEach(function(anchorTag) {
  var href = anchorTag.getAttribute('href');
  var splitHref = href.replace(/\.|\//g, '');
  anchorTag.setAttribute('href', '/'+splitHref);
});
```

For a list of methods used in the example, see below:

Query Selector All: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Get Attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

Set Attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

Replace: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace